# Automated emails when using trello and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, trello, zapier

Here's what I would like to accomplish. When a user submits a service request through our wordpress form, a new card is created in Trello. Once the work in completed the card is moved to a resolved list by us. What i would like to happen is to be-able to fetch the email in the card description. After the email address is returned, use it to populate a predefined email template that is then sent off to the user who filled out the form. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. You sure can! It'll take a couple of zaps. The big questions you have to answer for yourself are:

1. Will the trello board have cards that aren't part of this workflow?
2. Do you need to store data besides the user's email?

Here are the zaps:

**Zap 1**:

- New Form Entry (Trigger) - This can be any form that can send webhooks (or already has a zapier integration)
- Create Trello Card (Action) - configuration here depends on the answer to the above questions. In the simplest case, this will be card where the title will be an email. It might also include a label or something

**Zap 2**:

- Trello Card Moved to List (Trigger): Specify your "resolved" list
- Filter - optional, depending on if you need to filter out other cards (question 1)
- Send Email (Action) - You can use your email provider of choice or "Email by Zapier". Map in the email from step 1 of this zap as the destination and fill the body with whatever template you'd like.

Depending on your needs you can store more info on the trello card and make a more advanced filter, but at a basic level, this will do what you need.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: I’ll give it a try! Thanks!

Comment: great! If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and mark it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).

Comment: Worked! Thanks again!